# Yii2 button with two functions

Tags: yii2

Hi I need to create one button with 2 function save and then preview. For now I have 2 seperate buttons

For save

```
echo Html::submitInput('Save', ['name' => 'saveOnly','value' => '1', 'class' => 'btn btn-success']);
```

And for Preview

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://url.xxxx/something/show/<?php echo $mycontroler->id; ?>" class="-js-remove btn btn-warning btn-flat">View</a>
```

need to join this two buttons into one

Comment: You shoud do ajax save beforeSubmit and on submit preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably not join buttons, but redirect to preview after successful save:

```
public function actionSave() {
    // handle saving record

    return $this->redirect(['preview']);
}
```